# frameless window outside a window

Tags: node-webkit

Is it possible to get a new window without the frame outside the window(browser or webkit) like in the image?

[image: tooltip]

I've tried this in the package.json file of new window:

```
"window": {
    "position": "center",
    "width": 100,
    "height": 50,
    "show_in_taskbar": true
}
```

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: Why you need outside the window?

Comment: @Bulk is correct the answer is no. The only thing you can get to escape the window frame is an open <select> list if your window isn't tall enough to view the contents... But even then, you can't control it, it's up to the browser/operating system how it wants to deal with a long list that doesn't fit in the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, exceptions - only title attribute when hover, as on the screenshot